# Rounding date at the nearest year with R

Tags: r, date, rounding

I want to round an age at the nearest birthday of the person. How can I do that? I don't want to use if statements and packages. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: say you have a birth date: `06/29/90` , then find the age as of today: `diff <- (Sys.Date()- as.Date("1990-06-29"))` but this will give you age in days... to convert to years just divide by `365` : `diff/365` which is: `24.104111` .... hope it helps.. also see: `round()`

Comment: Rime it is what I do, in this case using round() will be 25, but if the result is 24.5 it will be also 25 and not 24 (24.5 is closer to 24 birthday). Beginner R, it is an example . Thanks!

Comment: @FrancescVE `round(24.5)` is actually 24 in statistical rounding (which R uses).

Comment: James it is true. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String comparisons is one way to do it.

```
birth.date <- as.POSIXct("1970-07-08")
current.date <- as.POSIXct("2014-07-31")

years <- as.integer(sub("-.*$", "", c(birth.date, current.date)))
month.days <- sub("^\\d+-", "", c(birth.date, current.date))

diff(years) + order(month.days)[2] - 1
```

You can do it with `difftime` but unfortunatelly you have to use days as unit, since months or years aren't supported (because they do not have constant length I suppose).

```
as.integer(ceiling(
    difftime(current.date, birth.date, units="days") / 365.2424
))
```

The **365.2424** bit accounts for leap years ([algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)).

Comment: Thanks Backlin! Exactly, it is the problem when I deal with difftime... The first way is ok but I don't know if it will be a little beat slower with a big DDBB. Thnaks!!!

Comment: Glad to help! You should however go for @James' answer, it's more efficient and elegant. My string comparison suggestion is essentially a dirty hack of his solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to subtract the years and then subtract a further 1 if the birthday is not been passed yet. Using `POSIXlt` objects is a bit easier than `Date` objects as you can extact the numbers without having to use many `as.integer`s.

```
calcAge <- function(dr,db)
{
    dr <- as.POSIXlt(dr)
    db <- as.POSIXlt(db)
    dr$year-db$year-(dr$mon<db$mon | (dr$mon==db$mon & dr$mday<db$mday))
}

calcAge(Sys.Date(), as.Date(c("1967-04-01","1991-08-12")))
[1] 47 22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
birth.date <- "2018-04-30"

library(lubridate) 
year(birth.date)
```